# how to store <List> into a database in winform C#?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have little experience setting up databases with C#. So, I want to store predefined contents of a list, also add values and remove values in session as the form runs.As from the list, URLs are blocked in the WebBrowser control, according to the contents. I will add snippets below.

```
private List<string> BlockList = new List<string>() { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.google.co.uk", "http://www.bing.com" };

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    string[] BlockArray = BlockList.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < BlockArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (e.Url.Equals(BlockList[i]))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says No!", "NO NO NO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); // Block List Error Message
        }
    }
}

private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = textBox2.Text;
    // Get if the user entered the right password
    GetPass pass = new GetPass(password);
    // Check this with a dialog result
    DialogResult result = pass.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        BlockList.Add(url);
        MessageBox.Show("Added " + url + " to blocklist.");
        textBox2.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says Wrong Password", "Wrong Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
}

private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = textBox2.Text;
    // Get if the user entered the right password
    GetPass pass = new GetPass(password);
    // Check this with a dialog result
    DialogResult result = pass.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        BlockList.Remove(url);
        MessageBox.Show("Removed " + url + " from blocklist.");
        textBox2.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says Wrong Password", "Wrong Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very broad question. Have you attempted to setup up any database yet?

Comment: do you want to know how to store list of strings to database

Comment: @Seminda pretty much, then how to remove and access them again.

Comment: there are many ways. you can store it as a comma separate string. or you can convert list to json and store. also you can design a table that keep each string as row of a table. What method you preferred.

Comment: @Seminda I think each row with string.

Comment: So you have to tell me this list include data per  user ? and what is your database (SQL server)

Comment: @Seminda This list is simply URLs inputted via textbox. Also, I have created a sql database called BlockList.

Comment: If you search e.g. https://www.bing.com/search?q=walkthrough+winforms+sql+database MS do "Walkthroughs" on how to access a database in C#.

Comment: then create a table with auto increment field and another field for value. then save list item one by one to your table